# How to launch cordova app from terminal

Tags: android, cordova, terminal, emulation

I don't ask how to run the app in a terminal from PC, but from the mobile only with a terminal emulator. I see the method for java app, but for the no-java app ?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, Cordova (Phone Gap) is wrapped inside a Java app.

Launching the surrounding Java app will automatically launch the Cordova App.